# Reshape a column into multiple columns

Tags: pandas

Im working with a df that looks like this:

```
Year Age Income
1945  1   234
1945  1   65
1945  2   234
...
1946  1   34
...
2015  5   34
```

I'd like to transform it to something like this, where income values fill the df and age is the index.

```
Age 1955 1956 1957 ... 2015
 0   
 1
 2 
 3
...
99
```

Comment: What do you expect to appear in the Age = 1, year = 1945 column? There are two different values shown. If this is a typo, my answer should work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `['Year', 'Age']` combinations were unique, you'd just need `set_index` and `unstack`

```
df.set_index(['Year', 'Age']).Income.unstack('Year')
```

---

**But they are not!**
So, you have to decide how to aggregate the groups of combinations.
Below is an example of using `sum`

```
df.groupby(['Year', 'Age']).Income.sum().unstack('Year', fill_value=0)

Year  1945  1946  2015
Age                   
1      299    34     0
2      234     0     0
5        0     0    34
```

---

**other aggregations**

```
df.groupby(['Year', 'Age']).Income.first().unstack('Year', fill_value=0)
df.groupby(['Year', 'Age']).Income.last().unstack('Year', fill_value=0)
df.groupby(['Year', 'Age']).Income.mean().unstack('Year', fill_value=0)
```

---

***[`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html)***
`pivot_table` <-> `pivot` is analogous to `set_index` <-> `groupby`
Meaning, `pivot_table` handles aggregation.

```
df.pivot_table('Income', 'Age', 'Year', 'sum', fill_value=0)
df.pivot_table('Income', 'Age', 'Year', 'first', fill_value=0)
df.pivot_table('Income', 'Age', 'Year', 'last', fill_value=0)
df.pivot_table('Income', 'Age', 'Year', 'mean', fill_value=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you'd like to `pivot` your table. Pandas [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html) is quite good.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[1945, 1, 234],[1946, 1, 65],[1945, 2, 234]])
df.columns = ['year', 'age', 'income']
df.pivot(index='age', columns='year', values='income')
```

Which looks like:

```
year  1945 1946
age
1     234  65
2     234  None
```